# Gmail can no longer search and those TLS handshakes make it freeze

Tags: gmail, firefox, monterey, macos

Firefox 95.0.2, OS 12.1
Since Big Sur gmail has been acting weird.  For one thing, it never stops loading.  The hourglass never goes away.  Also the empty boxes next to each email now no longer appear, but if I click where they used to be it works.  Many other small graphical elements are gone.

But the latest and worst is that it cannot search at all.  It hangs for a minute, and then just goes back to hanging.  As if I'd never tried to search anything.

I have a free version of Malwarebytes, so it is not constantly scanning, and I use zero add-ons.  Just a Bitwarden and UBlock extensions.

Comment: Are you asking about the Gmail Web App? Have you tried other browsers, incognito, no extensions?

Comment: No just using FF, I hate apps.  Weirdly, it seems to have resolved itself today.  I'm sure tomorrow it will un-resolve itself again.  I did try Safari and the same thing happened.

Comment: gmail.com is a web app. Do you believe this is specific to apple devices? I think this may fit better on https://webapps.stackexchange.com. Screenshots may help along with sharing what you see in the console and possibly in network requests. Also for future readers, FF = Firefox.

Comment: I consider gmail to me a website, since I've only ever used it in a browser.  Anyhow, in two days the issue has miraculously not reoccurred.  I did wipe my HD and install Monterey and then restored from a time machine backup for a different issue.  Previously I'd upgraded, this time it was a clean install.  It didn't take that long.  Maybe that did it.